# Outputting date from an array with bash

Tags: bash, date

I'm trying to put together a script that will detect when someone joins my network via DHCP and then will email me the details. The problem I'm having is with parsing the epoch time in the loop.

I've left out the code for getting the lease info, the error checking, diffing and sending of the email as it isn't the problem.

The format of the lease-information file is as follows:

```
epoch time   MAC address         IP Address        Hostname  DeviceID
4476705071   11:11:11:11:11:11   111.111.111.111   device1   *
7956915742   22:22:22:22:22:22   222.222.222.222   device2   *
```

I'm referencing that file with the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

LEASELEN=21600 # SET THE LEASE LENGTH TO 6 HOURS TO DETERMINE START OF LEASE

arrEND=($(cat /usr/local/bin/dhcp/leases.new | awk '{print $1}'))       # LEASE EXPIRY IN EPOCH
arrMAC=($(cat /usr/local/bin/dhcp/leases.new | awk '{print $2}'))       # MAC ADDRESS
arrIP=($(cat /usr/local/bin/dhcp/leases.new | awk '{print $3}'))        # IP ADDRESS
arrHOST=($(cat /usr/local/bin/dhcp/leases.new | awk '{print $4}'))      # HOSTNAME

echo 'Current and New connections to the network via DHCP:'
for ((i=0;i<${#arrIP[@]};i++)) # ITERATE FROM 0 TO TOTAL NUMBER OF ENTRIES
do
  arrSTART=$(expr ${arrEND[$i]} - $LEASELEN) # CALCULATE LEASE START FROM LEASE END
  arrSTARTH=`date -d @${arrSTART[$i]} +"%Y-%m-%d %T"` # CONVERT EPOCH TO HUMAN-READABLE
  echo "\""${arrHOST[$i]}"\" started using "${arrIP[$i]}" on "${arrSTARTH[$i]}" with MAC "${arrMAC[$i]}"." #OUTPUT
done

exit 0
```

The output is:

```
Current and New connections to the network via DHCP:
date: invalid date ‘@4476683471’
"device1" started using 111.111.111.111 on  with MAC 11:11:11:11:11:11.
date: invalid date ‘@’
"device2" started using 222.222.222.222 on  with MAC 22:22:22:22:22:22.
```

I suspect that part of the problem is that I've set the time too far in the future. Because if I add another 2 lines to the start of the lease file to make it:

```
epoch time   MAC address         IP Address        Hostname    DeviceID
1465374613   00:b0:d0:01:32:86   192.168.0.1       pre-device1 *
1465374820   00:00:00:00:00:00   0.0.0.0           pre-device2 *
4476705071   11:11:11:11:11:11   111.111.111.111   device1     *
7956915742   22:22:22:22:22:22   222.222.222.222   device2     *
```

I get the date in the first result, but no dates after that.

Output:

```
Current and New connections to the network via DHCP:
"pre-device1" started using 192.168.0.1 on 2016-06-08 04:30:13 with MAC 00:b0:d0:01:32:86.
date: invalid date ‘@’
"pre-device2" started using 0.0.0.0 on  with MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00.
date: invalid date ‘@’
"device1" started using 111.111.111.111 on  with MAC 11:11:11:11:11:11.
date: invalid date ‘@’
"device2" started using 222.222.222.222 on  with MAC 22:22:22:22:22:22.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: arrSTART is not an array. (Bad name chosen for that variable and the other one inside the loop.)

Comment: thanks @Mat You're very right, I didn't need them to be arrays, and renaming them from `arrSTART` and `arrSTARTH` to `varSTART` and `varSTARTH` has removed some of the confusion that led me to trying to reference the different indices in those non-existent arrays. (cool). and thanks again! I'm still getting `date: invalid date ‘@4476683471’` with the dates I set way in the future, That may just be because it's so far in the future though. If you put it up as an answer, I'll give you the kudos for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use `gawk` for this? Convert time with [strftime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["strftime"]="%s"} { print $4, "started using", $3, "on", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",$1), "with MAC", $2"."}' /usr/local/bin/dhcp/leases.new
```

O/P:

```
device1 started using 111.111.111.111 on 2111-11-11 18:11:11 with MAC 11:11:11:11:11:11.
device2 started using 222.222.222.222 on 2222-02-22 23:22:22 with MAC 22:22:22:22:22:22.
```

Comment: Very cool, I like that it works with those far-future times! I like it, thanks for the input @7171u. I'd +1  your answer, but I'm still too much of a n00b on UL (<15 rep) sorry.

Comment: Thanks @cas, I know :-) but the "answer" by 7171u was a nice-to-have, but did not the answer to my original question. The actual answer to it was provided by Mat in a comment below the original question. That's why I asked him to post it as an answer. Even so, I would have liked to +1 7171u's answer as it brought something to the party, even though it wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: An answer doesn't have to answer the question exactly as asked.  sometimes the best answers are those that answer the question the OP *should have* asked, or those that point out that the approach is wrong, and provide (or at least point to) a better way.  My first though when I saw your script was "why are you doing this in bash and not awk?  or perl?".  The fact that you can do something in bash doesn't mean that you should.  or that it's a good idea.

Comment: Hey again @cas, cool, thanks for the info. I'm using bash because there is quite a lot more going on than just getting the output, I'm doing a diff on it periodically (cron) to see if there's been any change as well as using ssmtp to send me an email notifying me of the new list of leases. Bash suited my needs best (within my abilities anyway).